# PHP can't load some libraries

Tags: php, wamp, firebird, interbase

First I'm using Windows 7 64 bits, WAMP 32 bits and firebird 32 bits.

I'm trying to use PHP with firebird or interbase, so I uncommented the following lines from my php.ini file:

```
extension=php_pdo_firebird.dll 
extension=php_interbase.dll
```

Then when I start WAMP the following errors occurs:

```
1)PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.3.13/ext/php_interbase.dll' - The specified module could not be found.
2)PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.3.13/ext/php_pdo_firebird.dll' - The specified module could not be found.
3)The program can not start because your computer is missing fbclient.dll. Try to reinstall it to resolve this issue.
```

What I have already tried:

```
1) Restart computer :)
2) Copy fbclient.dll to system32
3) Copy fbclient.dll to system32 and rename it to gds32.dll
4) Copy php_pdo_firebird.dll and php_interbase.dll from C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.13\ext to system32
5) Copy all dll from C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.13 and C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.13\ext to system32
6) Add C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.13\ext to my system PATH variable
```

Does anyone have any idea how I could fix this?
Thanks!!!

Comment: Try adding full path to dll in extension rule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WAMP is coming from this site ? http://www.wampserver.com/ if so ; why dont you the 64bits build instead of 32 ? Im' not sure that DLL 32bits can be use on Windows7 64bits.

Comment: Ok, I downloaded Firebird and Wamp 64 bits and everything is working fine! Thank you!

Comment: Also if you try what you did in your question: On Windows 64 the 64 bit files reside in System32, and the 32 bit files in SysWoW64 (but 32 bit applications will see that as if they are in System32)

Answer (score 2):

Fixed same problem on WAMPServer and BitNami WappStack, the error who search for php_interbase.dll and php_pdo_firebird.dll is really misleading: these library always were in that path!

---

For WAMP:
on Windows key registry i've found new key after installing wamp: C:\wamp\...\fb;
But no 'fb' folder was present at that address.

So I've created that folder and placed 'fbclient.dll' in it.

I've found 'fbclient.dll'  after firebird ODBC driver installation, http://www.firebirdsql.org/en/odbc-driver/, but I think it's not necessary to install firebird if you can find that dll otherway.

---

For BitNami WappStack.

Just add 'fbclient.dll' on C:ProgramFiles/BitNami/..../bin/php and everything runs well.

---

To see if your firebird driver runs well, this code fragment prints (on php page) all PDO drivers currently working:

```
<?php
 foreach(PDO::getAvailableDrivers() as $driver) {
  echo $driver.'<br />';
}?>
```